# handle special characters fetching from database via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm inserting data into database, at the time of inserting I convert my input `A&J Company` into `htmlentities($name)` and its store in the database like this `J &amp; D Company` when I'm fetching it via ajax and datatype is json It shows me like this `J &amp; D Company` in textfield so how can I handle it.

Comment: You don't need to worry about it, the HTML entity will automatically be decoded by the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/3e70h7uy/

Comment: if you are using php and mysql for storing your data in table then you can use mysql_real_escape_string() instead of htmlentities() this will do the same thing but never change and character while inserting to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roy McCrossan says the browser should show all characters decoded. In case it is not working you can use html_entity_decode().
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: at the time of fetching in textfield it is causing a problem